# What format is GCP's "Longrunningrecognize" output data in?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud's sample_long_running_recognize() to get audio transcripts as well as speaker diarization, but the output that it gives me is in LongRunningRecognizeResponse format which looks very similar to JSON, but not quite. How can I export the output of the LongRunningRecognizeResponse so I can put it in a pandas df?

I've tried to export it with

```
out = open(audio_in_file_path + "outputs/" + audio_in_file_name + "_out.json" , "w+")
out.write(response) # response is the output fyi
out.close()
```

but the format that the data is in is not actually JSON, so it messes up everything. I'm able to open the data on the console by calling the objects inside of `response` with something like `response.results[1].alternatives[0]` but I would much rather have it on a df.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the data is similar in structure to JSON, since the Cloud Speech-to-Text API response is in JSON format.

However the Python Client Library creates a Python object [1] from the JSON response, which is harder to automatically parse into JSON format. You can create a JSON parsable object that is easy to save by iterating through the structure of LongRunningRecognizeResponse. For example like this:

```
for res in response.results:
    for alt in res.alternatives:
        rows.append({"transcript": alt.transcript, "confidence": alt.confidence})

with open("results.json" , "w+") as file:
    json.dump(rows, file)
```

[1] https://googleapis.dev/python/speech/latest/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.types.LongRunningRecognizeResponse